# hipi gradle build error

Tags: hadoop, gradle, hipi

root@ubuntu:/usr/local/hipi# gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/usr/local/hipi/core/build.gradle' line: 8
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':core'.

  > Could not find method distributions() for arguments [build_7msgs7jcv6q1ci90h6pi2434k3$_run_closure2@39d1aa64] on project ':core'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.635 secs

```
Build.gradle code :
defaultTasks 'install'

allprojects {  
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
}

subprojects {

  apply plugin: 'java'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1'
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:2.7.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-jpeg:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-pnm:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-tiff:3.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacpp', version: '1.0'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.0'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.0'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.0', classifier: 'macosx-x86_64'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.0', classifier: 'linux-x86_64'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.0', classifier: 'windows-x86_64'
    testCompile "junit:junit:4+"
  }

}

task install {
  dependsOn(':tools:hibImport:jar')
  dependsOn(':tools:hibDownload:jar')
  dependsOn(':tools:hibInfo:jar')
  dependsOn(':tools:hibToJpeg:jar')
  dependsOn(':tools:hibDump:jar')

  dependsOn(':tools:covar:jar')

  doLast {
    println '\nFinished building the HIPI library along with all tools and examples.'
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using gradle 3.1 on hadoop 2.7

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in core folder's gradle file. Can you show me that file?
The content of core's directory gradle file should be :

```
   apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

jar {
    baseName = 'hipi'
    version = '2.1.0'
}

distributions {
    main{
        baseName = 'hipi'
        version = '2.1.0'
    }
}

javadoc {
  title = "HIPI - Hadoop Image Processing Interface"
  options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/",
                "http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/",
                "http://javadoc.metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/git/2.7.0/",
                "http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/")
}

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

Comment: This is my core directory's gradle file content

Comment: `code` apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

jar {
 baseName = 'hipi'
 version = '2.1.0'
}

distributions {
    main{
        baseName = 'hipi'
        version = '2.1.0'
    }
}

javadoc {
  title = "HIPI - Hadoop Image Processing Interface"
  options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/",
                "http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/",
                "http://javadoc.metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/git/2.7.0/",
                "http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/")
}

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

Comment: It is difficult to read, you compared with my solution..@AbhilashDesai